# Starred macro with delimited arguments?

Tags: macros, starred-version

My goal is to define a starred and a non-starred version of a macro `\foo` that will be called as `\foo arg {actual argument}` or `\foo* arg {actual argument}`.

So I tried the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\foo{\@ifstar\withstar\withoutstar}
\makeatother

\def\withstar arg #1{%
  With star: #1
}

\def\withoutstar arg #1{%
  Without star: #1
}

\foo* arg {actual argument}
\foo arg {actual argument}
```

but I get the error

```
! Use of \withstar doesn't match its definition.
l.67 \foo* 
           arg {actual argument}
```

However, if I change the definition of `\withstar` and `\withoutstar` to

```
\def\withstar #1{%
  With star: #1
}

\def\withoutstar #1{%
  Without star: #1
}
```

Then the calls `\foo* {actual argument}` and `\foo {actual argument}` work as expected. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a space between the start `*` and `arg`:

```
\foo* arg {actual argument}
```

But the parameter text of `\withstar` directly starts with `arg`:

```
\def\withstar arg #1{...}
```

because the space inbetween ends the command sequence `\withstar`.

Fix:

```
\makeatletter
\def\foo{\@ifstar\withstar\withoutstar}

\@firstofone{\def\withstar} arg #1{%
  \typeout{With star: #1}%
}
\makeatother

\def\withoutstar arg #1{%
  \typeout{Without star: #1}
}

\foo* arg {actual argument}
\foo arg {actual argument}

% End TeX job
\makeatletter\@@end
```

The space after curly braces is not ignored. `\@firstofone` is defined in the LaTeX kernel as such:

```
\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}
```

It is used as trick to insert the space after the command sequence `\withstar`.

Result:

```
With star: actual argument
Without star: actual argument
```

Comment: But `\withstar arg {some argument}` works fine. I guess I don't completely understand how spacing affects the macro parsing?

Comment: @dow A space after a command sequence (`\withstar`) is ignored. But a space is *not* ignored after other tokens like the start `*`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the use of `\@firstofone` in this case ?

Comment: @dow Answer is updated.

Comment: Thank you. On line 7, I believe you meant to say `\makeatother` (I would have fixed it myself, but it won't let me make edits that are less than 6 characters).